# How to determine the new order of rows in QTableWidget after sectionMoved event

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am creating an application in PyQt5 and have a `QTableWidgetItem` for which I allow the user to change the order of rows:

```
tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
```

I have connected a `onSectionMoved` slot to the `sectionMoved` signal. If I iterate over the contents of the first column in all rows inside `onSectionMoved` using

```
for row in range(tableWidget.rowCount()):
    print(tableWidget.item(row, 0).text())
```

I am still getting the contents of the first column in the old order. How can I get the contents in the new order?

**EDIT**

To make it more explicit: Assume I have a table

```
A AA AAA
B BB BBB
C CC CCC
```

Now, the user moves the first row behind the second one:

```
B BB BBB
A AA AAA
C CC CCC
```

My problem is that when iterating inside `onSectionMoved` I still get A B C as result and not B A C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must translate the row using the logical index:

```
header = tableWidget.verticalHeader()
for row in range(tableWidget.rowCount()):
    print(tableWidget.item(header.logicalIndex(row), 0).text())
```